# Using sample covariance to estimate eigenvalues of population covariance?

Tags: probability, eigenvalues

Suppose $X$ is an $m\times n$ data matrix with $m\approx \infty$ and $X_k$ consists of random $k$ rows of $X$. How do I estimate the spectrum of $X$ from $X_k$?

I can only reliably estimate $K$ eigenvalues where $K$ depends on $k$. Also, top eigenvalues of sample covariance of $X_k$ tend to be larger than top eigenvalues of $X$. How would I find $K$ and perform the bias correction in practice?

For the special case of $X$ consisting of IID normal entries, there may be [closed form expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4811191/distribution-of-kth-squared-singular-value-of-a-gaussian-matrix) that would allow me to perform bias correction. However, I'm interested in applying this to $X$ with unknown sampling distribution, ie, datasets like [these](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/datasets).